# Storing network via ERGM function: Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double' in

Tags: r, for-loop, network-programming, social-networking

Hi smart people out there! I am trying to create a function of ERGM to obtain the change of network statistics of each network when a random edge is removed.

```
Func <- function(network){
newergm <- ergm(network~edges+ nodematch('court', diff=F,keep=c(1:12,14:16))+nodematch('ideo',diff=F, keep=c(2,4))
              +nodeifactor('issue',base=c(5:9))+nodeifactor('supct')+nodefactor('meritor')
              +nodeifactor('womanpanel'))#, control= control.ergm(MCMC.burnin = 10000,MCMC.interval = 10000,seed=567))
chgstat <-as.matrix(unlist(summary.statistics(oldergm)-summary.statistics(newergm)))
return(chgstat)
}
```

The next step is to write a for loop to storage all the networks each time an edge is removed, here, I am manipulating deleting 3 edges for example,

```
for(i in 1:3  ){ 
   net3 <- asNetwork(g)     #the origial network from a igraph 
   tempnet[i]<- delete.edges(net3,as.edgelist(net3)[i,])  #create an new network by deleting an edge
   cs[i] <- Func(tempnet[i]) # apply predefined function to each new network
   table <- cbind(cs) 
 }
```

There's no error with the Func, but the for loop keep showing me "Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'" I don't understand why it is. This error doesn't occur if I run them without the loops. I am not sure is this the problem of the function or the storage of new networks. Thank you very much for your comments.

Comment: `cs` is a list?  Try  `cs[[i]] <- Func(tempnet[i])`; and `table = do.call(cbind, cs)` outside of the loop.

Comment: write another function to do what one loop iteration does, then `lapply` it

Comment: @sirallen I set the function returns the cs as a matrix, and it could set to be a list though. It still shows that error. I am wondering if R is confusing about how to storage the networks into the 'tempnet'?

Comment: @rawr Do you mean instead of using for loop, I need another function to do the iteration and lapply previous function?

Comment: something like `f <- function(i) {net3 <- asNetwork(g); Func(delete.edges(net3, as.edgelist(net3)[i, ]))}` then you can `do.call('cbind', lapply(1:3, f))` can't test it tho

Comment: @rawr thank you so much, it works perfectly!!!